# Is $2\delta(x) \neq \delta(x)$?

Tags: functions, special-functions, distribution-theory

$2\delta(x) \neq \delta(x)$ since, by definition,

[image]

Can this been seen graphically though?

[image]

If so, how?

If not, why is it that they are mathematically different but graphically the same?

Btw, I don't understand any precise definitions here so please dumb down your answers to the level of someone who knows basic Real Analysis and Partial Differential Equations, and just pretend I don't really know what the Dirac Delta function is. Thanks.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Definitions

Context: I thought the derivative of the sgn function was the Dirac Delta Function(al)/Distribution when it is really twice of it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function#cite_ref-2). I was thinking they would turn out to to be equal. Is it really wrong to say that the derivative of the sgn function is the Dirac Delta Function(al)/Distribution? I just can't visualize this.

Comment: Think of it as a functional defined as follows $\langle \delta, f\rangle:=f(0)$. Since $\delta$ is not a function, but a "distribution" I don't think you will gain much by trying to compare the graphs of $\delta$ and $2\delta$. It might be helpful to compare the graphs of functions whose "limits" give $\delta$ and $2\delta$.

Comment: @Sam Ah you mean like the ones here? http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/Dirac_function_approximation.gif

So if I multiply each by 2, they would be different...Thanks.

Sorry I forgot to add the context: I thought the derivative of the sgn function was the Dirac Delta Function(al)/Distribution when it is really twice of it (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signum_function#cite_ref-2). I was thinking they would turn out to to be equal. Is it really wrong to say that the derivative of the sgn function is the Dirac Delta Function(al)/Distribution? I just can't visualize this.

Comment: The sign makes a jump of size 2 at 0 (jumping from -1 to +1) hence it is only natural that the derivative of the sign function *in the distributional sense of the term derivative* should be twice the Dirac distribution at 0, not the Dirac distribution at 0.

Comment: If one plots a delta function, then its graph would be zero everywhere except the origin where it is infinite.  Since $2\cdot\infty=\infty$, the graph of twice a delta function looks the same as that of a single delta function although they are different objects in the sense of distributions.

Comment: The usual symbol for $2\,\delta(x)$ is a vertical vector of length $2$. This convention was chosen since integration will give $2\,H(x)+C$ with $H$ the [Heaviside step function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function) : we go two units higher at $x=0$ since   $\int_{-\epsilon}^{\epsilon}2\,\delta(x)\,dx=2$. Note that for $C=-1$ you get the $\operatorname{sgn}$ function.

Comment: @EPS Post as answer?